# Every Element on the page has the same XPATH: Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation

I am writing automated test cases for an open source app called "Featurehub" on github. It has to be run through docker container.
I am having the problem in obtaining xpaths for elements because all of them have a same path or css selector and selenium cannot distinguish between them.
For example,
I had to implement the login test case using an enter(return) statement to get into the password field:

```
def step_impl(context, email, password):
    context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//body[@id='app-container']/flt-glass-pane)[1]").send_keys(email)
    context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//body[@id='app-container']/flt-glass-pane)[1]").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//body[@id='app-container']/flt-glass-pane)[1]").send_keys(password)
    context.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//body[@id='app-container']/flt-glass-pane)[1]").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)
```

I have attached an image below in which you can see that there are no unique xpaths and nothing is in the source code either. [Screenshot: Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArTxU.png)
I tried recording it through Selenium IDE and it also shows same css selector for all clicks. [Screenshot: Selenium IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Swm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.find_elements` instead of `.find_element`:

```
elements = context.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//body[@id='app-container']/flt-glass-pane)[1]")
```

And then iterate through the list of elements:

```
for element in elements:
  element.click()
```

Or just access element of the list by index:

```
elements[0].send_keys(email)
elements[1].send_keys(password)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I believe that it only takes a single element and store it in the list because I'm getting the error:
          `elements[1].send_keys(password)
      IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: It works when multiple elements with the same xpath are present on the DOM of a page. But I think you have only one email/password form at a time, then your code is actually correct, because you have to look for an element every time it changes. Could you please provide a screenshot of your login page?

Comment: thank you for help, It basically looks like an android type form and clicking on any buttons doesnot show up anything in elements tab. Here is the screenshot, btw this is not only for the login scene but the whole app. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qof5r.png

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to check the website but try the below code:

You said all the XPaths are the same, in that case:

for email field, try:

```
(By.XPATH, "(//body[@id='app-container']/flt-glass-pane)[1]")
```

for password field, try:

```
(By.XPATH, "(//body[@id='app-container']/flt-glass-pane)[2]")
```

You don't need to pass Enter key.

Comment: Already tried doing it this way, it causes an exception saying no such element found on the password field  which has [2], thank you for help